# how to launch shortcut using combination of keys on windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a .bat file I want to launch only when something specific is typed on the keyboard.
For example, I want it to run only when I press ctrl and then W, O, R, and D.

How could I do this ?

I precise that I could do a bat triggered by a single letter macro of the first letter that checks for the following ones, but I would like to do it in a "cleaner" way, where the .bat only launches when the full word is typed.

Comment: [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25776089/2071807) seems relevant.

Comment: Yes, but I want to type a word, not a single lettre.